# How to Get TTetheringProfileInfo from ARemoteResource in ProfileResourceReceived Event?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tethering, delphi-xe6

I have been googling all day and keep seeing the same 10 examples for FireMonkey, apptethering and Delphi XE6.  I am new to XE6 and app tethering.  I thank you for any help I can get.

MY STORY
I have Delphi XE6.  I am trying to create a tethered FireMonkey application for the android platform.  I have a VCL application that will run on a server.  There will be many android tablets connecting to the server application at the same time.

The user pushes a button on a tablet which will cause a unique id to be sent to the server using the SendString method of the TTetheringAppProfile.  The server has a TetherProfileResourceReceived event and gets the unique id from the AResource.Value.  The server queries a database and gets a record. This is all good.

Now I need to send the record back to the SAME profile that sent the request.  Every example I have seen uses the item index to get the TTetheringProfileInfo for send string (TetherProfile.Resources.Items[0].Value).  I think I can't rely on the index because I will have multiple connections.  I want to send the response string right back to the requesting profile.

MY FAILED ATTEMPT

```
procedure TfrmTabletServer.POSTetherProfileResourceReceived(
  const Sender: TObject; const AResource: TRemoteResource);
var
  RequestID : Integer;
  SendRec := String;
  Requester : String;
begin

Requester := AResource.Name;
if AResource.ResType = TRemoteResourceType.Data then begin     
    RequestID := AResource.Value.AsInteger;
    SendRec := GetRecord(RequestID);
//this works but I cant rely on index name due to multiple connections
//POSTetherProfile.Resources.Items[0].Value = SendRec;

    //I would prefer to use SendString to keep the requests temporary 
    //I can't figure out how to get the TTetheringProfileInfo from the AResource
    POSTetherProfile.SendString('TTetheringProfileInfo from AResource?','Response ' +            ID.AsString, SendRec);
end;
```

MY RESOURCE
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Sharing_Data_with_Remote_Applications_Using_App_Tethering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while trying to get the working I still couldn't find a way of obtaining profile identifier from the parameters sent to the `OnResourceReceived` event.

The way I have solved this is to append the profile identifier to `AResource.Hint` string so the Hint looks like

```
"{OriginalHint};{ProfileID}"
```

This way I can always find the profile identifier by looking at the hint string.

This is not ideal but it works until we have the profile identifier passed as part of `AResource`.

Comment: in Berlin, I have access to AResource.Profile.Identifier.  Is this what you are looking for?